# How to Get Aggregated Sums At Specified Dates Using SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

I am trying to generate sums of transactions which is contained in a SQL Server table using this script:

```
Select Category,Sum(Items) as CategoryTotals 
from TransactionsTable  
where TransDate <=ReportingDate
Group By Category
```

I also have a list of dates for which this information is required as:

```
Select ReportingDates From AllMyDatesTable
```

Can anyone assist me with how I can structure a query to join the two queries to get a list of CategoryTotals at Specified dates similar to

```
Select ReportingDates,CategoryTotals from (My Two Tables)?
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Possibly by using the list of dates as the main query and cross apply to a subquery containing the details? This question is sufficiently vague enough that it is difficult to understand what you are asking. Perhaps you should start here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: How large are the tables?  Is performance an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? If you want to show dates even if no transaction is found go for `left join` instead of `inner join`

```
Select d.ReportingDates,t.Category,Sum(d.Items)
  from AllMyDatesTable d inner join TransactionsTable t 
    on d.ReportingDates = t.TransDate 
   and d.TransDate <= ReportingDate
 group by d.ReportingDates,t.Category
```